# How do I implement Authorization with a Single Page Application and REST Backend?

Tags: rest, authentication, content-management-system, authorization

I'm using Node.js with Loopback (based on Express) for the REST API. It has an ACL implementation that allows you to give/prevent access from/to parts of the API to a Role.

The front-end of the application is written with React and Redux.

The app will have a public and a private part, and I want people to be able to log in to `/admin`.

Next to the ACL for the REST resources, should there be a separate Authorization mechanism for the front-end?

Say I want to be able to access the `#/admin` page and my user is part of a role that allows you to look up information about users; How do I decide that my user can access the admin dashboard and how do I decide that my user may add a widget that makes use of the users API, to which his Role has been granted access?

Answer (score 0):

Use flashboard for loopback admin dashboard.
Its automatically generate your admin panel based on your models configs.

[vah7id.github.io/flashboard](http://vah7id.github.io/flashboard)